# Using stdout along with AND in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying multiple statements in if condition by using `AND`. It is working fine but, I'm unable to get the result of the last command

Please find my script below

```
Run Keyword If  "${app_type}" == ‘Verify'

...  Run Keywords

...    put directory  Data/scripts  ${verf directory}/

...    AND   Execute and verify command  date

...    AND   Execute and verify command  pwd

...    log   ${stdout}
```

I would like to get the output of the last command executed in `IF` condition

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the indentation to have the last keyword on the same level of `Run Keywords`:

`...  Run Keywords`

`...    (...)`

`...  Log    ${stdout}`

Or you could add another `AND` to `Run Keywords`